# Easy query on 2 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table, **TABLE1**, with two columns: SSN and Date.

I have another table, **TABLE2**, with SSN, name and Surname.

I want to view the Name and the Surname of the person who is associated to the SSN that appears the highest number of times in the first table (the one with SSN and Date)

Which query should I write?

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is probably to aggregation before joining:

```
select *
from (select t1.ssn
      from table1 t1
      group by t1.ssn
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     using (ssn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT t1.ssn, t2.name, t2.surname, count(*) as vol
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t1 on t1.ssn = t2.ssn
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, see the answer from @forpas using the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which returns the `SSN` that appears the most in `table1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE SSN = (SELECT SSN FROM table1 GROUP BY SSN ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

With an index on `SSN` (which I assume exists) this is the fastest way to get the result.